# How do i ignore or remove " between words in field

Tags: netezza

I have a field in a table where the data is one of the following:

- ABC" D
- "Add"b"

How can I ignore the " character?

I am new to netezza and have some sql knowleged

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this many different ways.  I recommend `translate`

```
select  translate(test.test_data,'"','')
from (select 'ABC" D' as test_data
union all
select '"Add"b"') test
```